# Split numerical values and find unique numbers

Tags: google-sheets, split, unique, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

I have a data set where column A looks like this:

```
80419, 80038, 9306
7742
10638
10638
10694, 7738
8958, 7741
7706, 8537
7747, 8954
7747, 8954
7742
9907, 80465
10638
7747, 8954
7706, 8537
80040, 80043
80040, 80043
7747, 8954
80040, 80043
80040, 80043
80043
80043
80040, 80043
80040, 80043
80040, 80043
80040, 80043
80040, 80043
```

Ultimately, I would like to pull the unique values from this data set.

I have tried to split these values first but I am running into an issue where '80040' becomes 8004. I need to retain 0's on the ends of the values.

Comment: So how are you splitting it? Show what you tried that did not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, A1:A), ",")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: you can wrap it into `SORT()` if you want it sorted

Comment: This worked perfectly, player0. Thank you for the quick response and the correct answer!